# self actor hangs in repl

Tags: scala, actor

I'm following along in Programming in Scala edition 1 30.3 (p589). There it explains that you can use 'self' as an actor for the current thread to debug actors in the repl. However, when I follow along with Scala 2.9.1 the thread hangs on receive.

```
$ scala -unchecked -deprecation
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.Actor._

scala> self ! "hi"

scala> self.receive { case a => a }
[hangs - should be "res1: Any = hi"]
```

I check with Scala 2.7.7 and it works as expected. How can I get this to work with Scala 2.9.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because 2.9.1 REPL each input run differentThread.

see 
https://gist.github.com/1324774

please use "-Yrepl-sync" option ,Than each input same Thread.

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/settings/ScalaSettings.scala#L149

Comment: Thanks! Putting the send and receive on a single input line works (whether they are in a block or not). The REPL option is very nice though.