# How to return a value from receive method in scala actor model

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor

How to return a value from receive method in scala actor model, when all the variables are immutable.

```
title =
  receive{
    case title: String => title
  }
```

when i tried the above it says found Unit.

Is it possible to return a value from within receive.

Comment: Despite scala actors are deprecated your code should work fine. To make result immutable you should replace `title =` with `val title =`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. Error is somewhere else. Tested in `scala 2.9.3` with [`-Yrepl-sync`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059162/406435) option:

```
scala> import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.Actor._

scala> self ! "test"

scala> val title = receive { case title: String => title }
title: String = test
```